# Can `dict` replace `list` when memory is not a concern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, containers, built-in-types

I could represent any list as a dictionary whose keys are the valid list indices, and whose values are the list's items. E.g., `[5, 6, 'a']` would be represented as `{0:5, 1:6, 2:'a'}`.

In terms of asymptotic time and memory complexity, the `dict` representation is identical to `list`. `list` uses less memory by a constant factor.

If memory is not an issue, is it true that I can always use `dict` instead of lists and other sequences (to gain the flexibility of using arbitrary keys, and to slightly standardize the code by reducing the number of different containers used)?

Comment: Accessing dict items in order requires an `O(n log n)` operation.

Comment: @PavelAnossov: according to http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, `dict` is amortized O(1) for element access. If "in order" means the same as "in order of list's indices", then it would be O(n): `for k in range(len(dict_)): yield dict_[k]`.

Comment: lists are ordered; dictionaries are not. Of course, you may always use *OrderedDict* from *collections* package

Comment: @max Don't loop by index. `[v for k, v in sorted(dict.items())]` is the correct solution to that problem.

Comment: @Lattyware: if my dictionary represents a list, by construction its keys are integers `0`, `1`, ..., `len(dict_)-1`. So I know their order without having to sort. (Of course, if I do use dictionaries to store other keys, it's a different story. But I was only talking about replacing lists with dictionaries.)

Comment: @max Which is another example of why this is a bad idea. You are missing my problem, which is looping by index - it's not a good way to iterate in Python. The language is designed around iterating by value.

Comment: @Lattyware: sorry maybe I'm misunderstanding you. My loop seems to be identical to yours under the constraint that my dictionary represents a list (so that I know that its keys are identical to `range(len(dict_))`). The only difference between my loop and yours is that you spend `O(N logN)` on your loop due to the sorting time, while I spend `O(N)`. Why is it not a good idea to use my loop?

Comment: @max Readability is far more important than optimization in 99% of cases, beyond that, what if you need to pass those values into a function that takes an iterable? Python iterates by value, so you can use your special method of iterating, but nothing else will. Python is designed around iteration by value. Iterating by index will produce code that is less flexible.

Comment: @Lattyware: if I need to pass such a dictionary into a function that needs an iterable, I would pass `dict_.values()` rather than `dict_`. Since this is Python 3, it involves no copying, and it will serve a perfectly fine iterable. There's no performance hit from this, AFAIK. I do agree with you that it's confusing and annoying to do it every time.

Comment: @max That presumes it's alright for those values to be out of order.

Comment: @Lattyware Using a algorithm that does exactly what you want instead of an that incidentally does the same thing for expected inputs is not premature optimization, it's common sense. In addition, using an O(n) time, O(1) space algorithm instead of an O(n log n) time, O(n) space algorithm is not premature optimization either, it's a good habit if you ever intend to write anything larger than utility scripts. And **here**, "don't loop by index" is just a brainless mantra -- getting the values for the keys 0, 1, .. n is *exactly what we're trying to do*, and sorting instead just obscures that.

Comment: @Lattyware: Oops, you're right. I would either have to pass `(dict_[k] for k in range(len(dict_)))`, which is insane; or else create a subclass of `dict` that redefines `__iter__` to do that by default, which means I can't use non-integer keys any longer, thus removing the flexibility I was going after. So the answer to my question is negative, if only due to the interface issues.

Comment: @delnan My point isn't that using my method is the best option here - my point is that using a `dict` where you really want to use `list` will produce sub-optimal code. The point of saying "don't loop by index" here isn't that looping by value produces great code, it's that we should avoid the situation which *forces* us to loop by index for performance.

Comment: @Lattyware I agree with that. I objected to your presentation of it.

Comment: @delnan The issue is my argument is broken up among my answer and many comments. If you view part of it in isolation, I can understand your distaste for it. Unfortunately, I had to explain myself further to get my point across and that was the only real way to do it.

Comment: I don't really follow the discussion: mimicking list behavior with a dict is not only harder to read/unpythonic, but is also about twice as slow in a simple loop (compared to looping through an actual list). That is - there is absolutely no reason why you should ever do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefer the data structure that makes the most sense given the data going into it.

`dict`s are great, but, for example, they don't hold order: so if you want to iterate over the values in order you will have to sort based on key, which produces complexity and makes it hard to read.

In general, it's unlikely that using `dict`s everywhere instead of `list`s will make meaningful speed increases to your application - it's premature optimization.

What is far more important is what makes sense to readers and modifiers of your code, and what is most suitable for the data you are trying to store. Where you are storing a sequence of data, use a `list`. Where you are storing a mapping, use a `dict`.

Comment: I didn't hope that `dict` would increase the speed; I was just hoping that they wouldn't reduce it - and yet offer more flexibility for future changes in key types. As to the order, the only order that lists "maintain" are the order of indices. The dictionaries that replace lists (hence have keys 0, 1, 2, ...) can offer such order for free: just iterating with `for k in range(len(dict_)): yield dict_[k]`.

Comment: And iterating by index is ugly and inefficient. There is no need to use `dict`s with the vague chance of needing them later. Use a `list`, if you find you need a different collection later, use a different one. Use what makes sense.

Comment: @max adding to Lattyware's - very un-Pythonic

Comment: I think you are not being clear enough if you say `it's unlikely that using dicts everywhere instead of lists will make meaningful speed increases to your application - it's premature optimization.` If you use `dict` to mimic list behavior it can't be called an optimization as it will be notably slower (in a simple loop) :)

Comment: A `dict` wourd be OK for *sparse* list, where most of the elements will not be initialized explicitly. It's pretty easy to write a dict subclass that acts like a list but only stores values that were explicitly set.